# validate multiple inputs for css property

Tags: jquery, css, validation, input

I have multiple input fields on my page. I Regex them with a css red border when invalid data is entered.

I want to simply check ALL input fields at once for that class before inserting data to DB. The following was my idea but fails.

```
if($('input').css("border") == "2px solid red"){//1 or more red borders to flag
    alert('yes');
}else{
    alert('no'); // there are no red borders in all inputs 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't check your CSS class...

Re-run your validation function prior to submitting.  Use that to check if everything is good.  Also, don't forget to validate server-side as well!

Comment: So, on click, call all regex functions again, and trip a flag if any fail?  Seems like it would work.

Comment: Yep.  Normally, I have one function that validates everything, sets CSS on the form as appropriate, and returns `true`/`false`, whether or not there is a problem.  This is a somewhat lazy approach, as it would be better to check fields one by one during the time the user is filling out the form, but it works well when you go to submit.  For your case, I'd just make a `validateAll()` function that calls all of your individual validators and returns `true`/`false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put red borders to all a group of inputs you can do it this way

```
$("input").css('border','1px solid red');
```

Otherwise if yo want to check via jquery if an input has a class, yo can use the .hasClass method.

And lets say you have a function for validate named validate() that will return false or true at his execution and a certain group of inputs with an especific class

```
<input class="validate" type="text" />
<input class="validate" type="text" />  

$(".validate").each(function(){
 if(  !validate( $(this).val() ) ){
 $(this).css('border','1px solid red'); //add red border
 $(this).focus(); //focus the element
 alert("you didn't pass the validation"); //alert message error
 return false; //stops the loop
}
```

});

This will go over all inputs with class validate and will show the error message for an input that doesn't satisfy the function for validation